# Series for constructing integers

Tags: combinatorics, integers

I'm not sure about the proper terminology for what I'm asking, so bear with me:

I want to list all ways one can generate an arbitrary integer from positive multiples of the integers less than and including its self.  For example...

```
1=1*(1)
2=2*(1) or 1*(2)
3=3*(1) or 1*(1)+1*(2) or 1*(3)
4=4*(1) or 2*(1)+1*(2) or 2*(2) or 1*(1)+1*(3) or 1*(4)
...
```

Is there a name for these types of combinations?  How would one go about generating all of the combinations for an arbitrary integer, aside from by brute force?  Is there a way to know, a priori, *how many* such combinations exist for an arbitrary integer?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are known as [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).  They are usually described not in terms of multiples as you have done, but simply as all ways to write a nonnegative integer $n$ as a sum of positive integers (ignoring order).  This is equivalent since you can group together all copies of the same integer in the sum; for instance, the partition $4=2+1+1$ corresponds to your expression $4=1\cdot 2+2\cdot 1$.

The number of partitions of a nonnegative integer $n$ is written $p(n)$.  There is no nice closed formula for $p(n)$, but this function has been very extensively studied.  You can find a lot of basic information on the Wikipedia page linked above.  For instance, $p(n)$ is known to be asymptotic to $\frac{\exp(\pi\sqrt{2n/3})}{4n\sqrt{3}}$ when $n$ is large.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n)x^n=\frac{1}{\prod_{i\geq1}(1-x^i)}\tag{1}
$$
and the pentagonal theorem
$$
\prod_{i\geq 1}(1-x^i)=\sum_{n\geq1}(-1)^n(x^{n(3n-1)/2}+x^{n(3n+1)/2})
$$
the relation 
$$
\left(\sum_{n\geq1}(-1)^n(x^{n(3n-1)/2}+x^{n(3n+1)/2})\right)\left(
\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n)x^n
\right)=1
$$
implies that for $n>0$, one has the recurrece relation
$$
p(n)=p(n-1)+p(n-2)-p(n-5)-p(n-7)+\dotsb\tag{2}
$$
with the understanding that $p(n)=0$ for $n<0$. Equation (2) gives a way to compute $p(n)$ recursively.